# Verilog Testbench - wait for specific number of clock cycle edges

Tags: verilog, testbench

In my testbench, I want to wait for two events in sequence: one after 60000 clock cycles and next after additional 5000 clock cycles

I know I can wait for clock edges using statement @(posedge clk), however how do I wait for specific number of clock edges, say 6000th positive clock edge etc.

Answer (score 2):

Put your `@(posedge clk)` in a for loop:

```
for (i=0; i<60000; i=i+1)
   @(posedge clk) ;
```

Comment: I think the code you gave would wait for each of the 60K clock edges.I want to skip sensing first 59999 positive clock edges and only sense 60K th positive clock edge.

Comment: You can't skip a clock cycle unless you know there was one.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is very basic.

```
repeat (5) begin
  @(posedge clk);
end
```

is much better.